# How to get position of element after appending it to parent in javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, append, element

```
var t = 0, i = 0;
var letter = document.createElement('span')
letter.id = "x" + t + "x" + i;
letter.innerHTML = text[t];
highlight.appendChild(letter);
var position = $("#" + "x" + t + "x" + i).position();
```

This is the code and it keeps saying the letter is undefined.

Comment: IDs cannot start with numbers.

Comment: the problem was that the positions are not updated for line breaks

Comment: In the HTML 5 specification ID's can start with numbers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that `highlight` is an actual DOM Node (not undefined) and `text` has been defined previously, the most probable cause is executing the script before the DOM has loaded. Try putting your script at the bottom of your html just before the closing `</body>`-Tag.

Here is a fiddle with the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/n9xk85b7/

Comment: var text = ["ab", "cde"];
var hightlight = document.getElementById('highlight');

var t = 0, i = 0;
var letter = document.createElement('span')
letter.id = t + "x" + i;
letter.innerHTML = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf<br>";
highlight.appendChild(letter);
var letter = document.createElement('span')
letter.id = t + "x" + i;
letter.innerHTML = text[t];
highlight.appendChild(letter);
var position = $("#" + t + "x" + i).position();

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "top: " + position.top + ", left: " + position.left;

Comment: when you see that a linebreak appears by another appended element it does not get the right top offset

Comment: I found that if I don't use append but innerhtml it works